# What is the correct (i.e., precise) term for a vector of the form $(a_1,...,a_n)$?

Tags: notation, vectors

What is the correct (i.e., precise) term for a vector of the form $(a_1,...,a_n)$?

I ask this because my definition of vector is that it is an element of some vector space, this means that whenever we say vector it may be non-obvious that I'm talking of one of the above form (functions are vectors, for example).

Would the precise term be $n$-tuple?

Comment: Yep, $n$-tuple is good.

Comment: aktually a tupel can be a tupel of functions as well....

so if you explicitly want to say you have a Vector only with real numbers, I would stick to vector in $R^n$...  of course you are not limited to this.... you can make a tupel/vector out of any space.. for excample $M:=\mathbb{R}\times C_4(7,9)\times \mathbb{N} $ here you have a vector in M....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refer to a vector which is an element of the vector space $F^n$, say "a vector in $F^n$".

You can also say "$n$-tuple" or "$n$-tuple of real/complex numbers".